# Not able to display the json through Flask App in the d3 template

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, python-3.5

Here the code of the flask app:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__,)
with open(r"data.json") as f:
  data = json.load(f)
@app.route("/result")
def index():
    return render_template("bars.html",data=json.dumps(data))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=2000,debug=True)
```

Here is the template:

```css
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .tickSize(0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#ca0020","#f4a582","#d5d5d5","#92c5de","#0571b0"]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");    
d3.json({{data}}, function(error, data) {

  var categoriesNames = data.map(function(d) { return d.categorie; });
  var rateNames = data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; });

  x0.domain(categoriesNames);
  x1.domain(rateNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .style('opacity','0')
      .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style('font-weight','bold')
      .text("Value");

  svg.select('.y').transition().duration(500).delay(1300).style('opacity','1');

  var slice = svg.selectAll(".slice")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.rate); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(0); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
      });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function (d) {return Math.random()*1000;})
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  //Legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; }).reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity","0");

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); });

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) {return d; });

  legend.transition().duration(500).delay(function(d,i){ return 1300 + 100 * i; }).style("opacity","1");

});

</script>
```

Here is the json that I have saved in file `data.json` and tried to load and display using the flask app:

```
[
    {
        "categorie": "Student", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 0, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 4, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 12, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 0, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Liberal Profession", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 1, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 21, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 13, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 18, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Salaried Staff", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 22, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 15, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Employee", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 12, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 7, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 18, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 13, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Craftsman", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 15, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 9, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 12, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "categorie": "Inactive", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Not at all"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Not very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 6, 
                "rate": "Medium"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 2, 
                "rate": "Very much"
            }, 
            {
                "value": 3, 
                "rate": "Tremendously"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have got this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'
```

I tried using `safe`, but it gave me something other error:

```
GET http://localhost:2000/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 404 (NOT FOUND)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (result:55)
    at Object.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.i (d3.v3.min.js:1)
(anonymous) @ result:55
t @ d3.v3.min.js:1
i @ d3.v3.min.js:1
load (async)
Cn @ d3.v3.min.js:1
ao.json @ d3.v3.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ result:53
```

Please let me know what I can do to get the effect similar to: https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad

Comment: None of the solutions worked.

Comment: Please let me know if someone had tried the example I have shared. Because then only one can understand the issue.